# RowOrder Policy with time data does not work

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am trying to set a row order policy ( ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/roworder-policy ). However I am tying to apply it only on time logging column. But it is not working. The timestamp is not in UNIX format though. Do I have to combine with any other attribute ?

Comment: How do you know that it is not working? What is the type of the column?

Comment: It is giving me the same output when I write `take 10` . although I set descending policy. The type is datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row order policy is intended to improve performance by ordering the rows in the internal storage format of Kusto, it does not have any semantic impact, see this sentence from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/roworderpolicy):

[image]

Since row order policy consumes computing resources, it is advised to avoid applying it if there is no performance need. If there is such a need, using a [partitioning policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/partitioningpolicy) has a much higher performance impact and will most likely work much better.